# getting and adding values together from a checkbox

Tags: java, servlets

i currently have a servlet that displays some baseball cards and its values. i want to be able to list them in a checkbox and be able to choose the cards you want to sell. the servlet would then take the cards you checked and add those values up and show the total. i have most of it done except i cant get the values from the check boxs and sum them up.

this is my jsp

```
 <form name="CashOut.jsp" method="post">
<table>   
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${winingCards}">
        <tr>  
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cardvalue" value="${entry.price}"><h1>PRICE<h1>${entry.price}$</h1><br><img src="photofolio/images/cardimages/clevelandindians/${entry.name}.png" align="middle" style="max-height:25%; max-width:25% "/>
            </td>   
            </tr>       
    </c:forEach>     
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this mis my controller

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
         JFrame parent = new JFrame();
         int sumTotal = 0;
        String[] items =request.getParameterValues("cardvalue");
        for(String item : items){

             sumTotal=+sumTotal;

        }

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You Cashed Out with: "+sumTotal);
         request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/photofolio/index.html" ).forward(
                 request, response );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats your issue? is this `items` contains `null`?

Comment: i dont know how to get the price value from the jsp so i can sum them.

Comment: with this `request.getParameterValues("cardvalue")` you will get all the values right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to

```
double sumTotal = 0;

for(String item : items){

     sumTotal += Double.parseDouble(item);//convert string to int
     //Its equals to sumTotal = sumTotal + Double.parseDouble(item);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You Cashed Out with: "+sumTotal);
```

Comment: this gives me a error HTTP Status 500 - For input string: "10.5"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message For input string: "10.5"

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10.5"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: _For input string: "10.5"_ so its not number its a decimal number. I edited my answer.

Comment: yes  im sorry, i forgot its a decimal value. thank you very much. any idea  how i can i can forward this page to my index page? i get HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been committed  when i use request dispatcher.

Comment: I didn't expect that your code will produce that exception. need more